# JavaScript scope resolve time

Tags: java, javascript, object, scope

I'm writing an app that loads javascript dynamically using rhino(or a browser); I got 2 files:

```
// in a file called fooDefinition.js
var definition = {
    foo: function(data){return bar(data)},
    loadFile: "barLib.js"
}
```

now, `bar()` is defined like this:

```
// in a file called barLib.js
function bar(data){
    return data + " -> bar!";
}
```

This is what I want to do:

1. load `fooDefinition.js` into the environment
2. read the value of `loadFile` (in this case: `"barLib.js"`) and load the file (NOTE: load the file through external mechanism, not through javascript itself!)
3. call `foo`

external mechanism & example usage (Java pseudo code):

```
// assume engine is a statefull engine (rhino for example)
String str = /*content of fooDefinition.js*/;
engine.eval(str);
String fileToLoad = engine.eval("definition.loadFile");
engine.load(IOUtils.readFileToString(new File(fileToLoad)));
String result = engine.eval("definition.foo('myData')");
```

I've tried this in Google Chrome's JS console and no error was thrown

I wonder is this the correct way of accomplish such task?

**TL;DR:
Are the attributes of an object loaded and *checked* when the object is defined?**

Comment: Scope is resolved at call-time.

Comment: What do you mean with "load the file through external mechanism, not through javascript itself!"? It is pure javascript, or javascript within an HTML web page?

Comment: basically, I'll be loading the javascript manually through Java

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol So is my usage valid?

Comment: Is your `engine` statefull? my mean is, whether it keeps track of defined variables or not? if so, seems your way is correct if you use `engine.eval("definition.foo('myData')");`

Comment: yes it's statefull, sorry my bad, typed the whole thing in a hurry. It is indeed `engine.eval("definition.foo('myData')");`; I've updated the question

Comment: Now, whats your question?

Comment: What do you mean? this page is the question I'm asking...

Comment: you asked is this way is correct? ans: yeah `:)`

Comment: @ABFORCE do you want to put the answer as an answer? so that I can give you the credits :)

Comment: really? I love credits :D

Comment: yep, that would help future visitors too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `engine` is statefull that is it keeps track of defined variables, yes your approach is corrent and will work as expected
But if it is not, your way will fail, because when you call the following

```
String fileToLoad = engine.eval("definition.loadFile");
```

your engine haven't any info about `definition` object and as a result it return an exception (in JavaScript).

It seems your engine is statefull and all things will work correctly